# silverlight project output to sharepoint 2010 feature resource?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I've seen a long time ago a tip to easily add a silverlight project output to a sharepoint project. However I don't remember what was the tip.

My solution is like this :

- MySolution

  - MySolution.SharePoint.WebPart project
  - MySolution.SharePoint.SL project

My goal is to build a webpart that renders the silverlight inclusion (with specific parameters, that's why I cannot use the OOB silverlight webpart).

In visual Studio, what is the easiest way to automatically include the silverligth project output in the webpart resources ?

thx
steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering myself.

the procedure is described here : [Create a Silverlight 4 Web Part for SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff956224.aspx).

The idea is to add a module in the SP project, and to setup the module to add the project output of the silverlight project.

thx anyelse